# Joomla 2.5 pagination settings from administrator

Tags: joomla2.5

I am beginner to joomla, currently using version 2.5. I have came across a problem with pagination. In my site pagination on all the pages were working well, but suddenly, I don't see any pagination for any page. I don't realized, what setting from admin panel I have changed. I have checked the settings from the Article Manger->options->Shared Options, but all are ok. 
Is there any other settings in admin panel to show pagination?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realize the problem, when I put `<jdoc:include type="module" name="cblogin" />` in my template file, then all the pagination links get disappeared. I have also checked with putting below code -

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$mods = JModuleHelper::getModules('cblogin');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mods[0]);
```

but, nothing has changed. Is there any other solution to load module into html code?

Answer (score 0):

You must seach this in Article Manger->options->"First Tab"

But it can be also placed in the main menu item: Menu->MainMenu->"First item" general settings...

Comment: thanks for reply. will u please elaborate. I didn't find any settings there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add modules to articles, one way is to add a custom position to the article then assign the module to that position. In the article editor add this code

```
[loadposition myNewPosition]
```

Then you can assign any module to myNewPosition on the position option. Make sure the module is assigned to all pages.